# Issue with accessing hard drive, I was able to recover data fine until an issue came and had to restart my pc [solved]

Tags: hard-drive

[image: the warning]

Using AOMEI Backupper, I was trying to recover the data in this drive, with 561 bad sectors.
After restarting the PC because AOMEI had to, the drive is now inaccessible
It kept freezing every time I tried to click on it but now it doesn't even do that but gives me this warning shown above.

Answer (score 0):

this is not true, AOMEI destroyed my 3 disks, they were all new. I just wanted to simply clone it and the progress led was visible while I did nothing, I exited properly and the disk was simply no longer available. A strange phenomenon occurred, however, the installed system continued to load from it, but nothing happened when it was put into an extender, not even an operating system could interpret the file system on it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).